# SVN Can't revert 'mydir' without reverting parent

Tags: svn

I just wanted to revert a whole directory so I typed:

```
svn revert mydir
```

Then I realized it was wrong and it should have been:

```
svn -R revert mydir
```

After typing this last command I receive the error "svn: E155038: Can't revert 'mydir' without reverting parent".

I've moved to 'mydir' and then try the `svn -R revert .` but still it returns the same error.

How can I revert this directory recursively so I can get the previous version from the server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that 'mydir' was not added to the SVN yet so there was not a previous version to revert to. If you revert parent directory you will lose any changes done in 'mydir' directory.

Comment: And what if instead "parent" I have "children" in the end of error message?

Comment: @arche89 svn revert <dir> --depth infinity